# access UINavigationController from subclass of UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UINavigationBar subclass, is it possible someway from that UINavigationBar to get my UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good design pattern. You should put the navigation logic into your view controllers. If you have controls (such as buttons) in your custom navigation bar, you should also handle these events in your view controllers.

Note that the `UINavigationBar` does not deal with the controllers (it should be the other way round), rather it deals with the `UINavigationItem`s, which will look different according to if they are on top of the navigation stack or not.

There is a **trick** to make your custom navigation bar the `navigationBar` property of your view controller's navigation controller. Normally this is a read-only property. But you can put it into your navigation controller in Interface Builder in Xcode, and then **change the class name** in the inspector **to your custom class**. You will then be able to refer to your bar with the usual `self.navigationController.navigationBar` from within your view controller.